# Magento 2.3.4: Speed up layered navigation filters

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter, speedoptimization

Is there a way to speed up layered navigation filters on Magento 2.3.4?
Filters with a lot of products are taking too long to load.

Any help would be appreciated.